# What is the CSS selector for elements which have HTML5 [hidden] set to true?

Tags: css, html

What is the CSS selector for elements which have HTML5 [hidden] set to true?

I do not want to select elements whose [hidden] is false.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[hidden]{

 }
```

Or

```
element[hidden]{


}
```

The syntax is

```
[attribute=value]
```

The `value` is optional

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full list of all selectors:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

if your hidden property of element is a attribute like:
`<p hidden="true">`
then the selector is 
`var my_hidden_element = $("p[hidden=true]");`

Comment: $ is not a part of CSS brother. It is jquery

Comment: I thought he asked the selector to find elements with hidden attribute.

Comment: Yes. CSS selector.

Comment: I removed my down vote cause I don't want o degrade your efforts. But CSS selectors are there.

Comment: Thanks, that probably misunderstanding.